# Python Requests Redirect using specific token

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
import config
import datetime
import io
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL
import requests
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
import time
import uuid

guid =              str(uuid.uuid4())
engine =            create_engine('postgresql://<user>:<pwd>@igers.db.com:8192/ibdrs?sslmode=require')
path =              'D:/Python-Scripts/SIM/bin/'
jsonFiles =         os.listdir(path)
maxSnapshotQuery =  '''SELECT MAX(Snapshot) AS Snapshot FROM %s''' 

#disable requests SSL warnings
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

def createSession() :
    global session
    sessionURL = 'https://api.com/users/whoami'
    session = requests.session()
    session.get(sessionURL, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False)
    return session

def createJob(session) :
    global data
    #use the Session to send Json to the Jobs API
    simURL = 'https://api.com/jobs'
    r = session.post(simURL, json=rawJson, verify=False)
    rjson = r.json()
    docID = rjson['id']

    #Determine Job status
    docStatusURL = simURL+'/'+docID
    docStatusJson = session.get(docStatusURL, verify=False)
    docStatus = docStatusJson.json()['status']


    while docStatus != 'Complete' :
        time.sleep(10)
        docStatusJson = session.get(docStatusURL, verify=False)
        docStatus = docStatusJson.json()['status']
        if (docStatus == 'Failed') :
            break
            print('Job Status : %s' %docStatusURL)
            exit()
        continue

    #Once the job is complete, retrieve the attachment ID
    attachments = docStatusJson.json()['attachments']
    fileID = attachments[0]['id']

    #set the file download location and retrieve the file
    docURL = 'https://api.com/jobs/%s/attachments/%s' % (docID, fileID)
    data = session.get(docURL, verify=False)
    return data

def loadData(data, engine) :
    stream = data.content

    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stream.decode('utf-8')))
        df['Snapshot'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        df.where(df.notnull(),None)
        dateCol = [col for col in df.columns if 'Date' in col or 'date_' in col or '_date' in col]
        for col in dateCol:
            df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

        if file.split(".")[0] in ["DCE"] :
            df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, schema = 'sim_and_tt', if_exists='append', index=False)
        else :
            df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], engine, schema = 'sim_and_tt', if_exists='replace', index=False)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print('Loading data to the database failed for ' + file)
        error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
        print(error)


for file in jsonFiles:
    tableName = file.split(".")[0]
    try:
        snapshotDate = pd.read_sql_query(maxSnapshotQuery %tableName, engine, parse_dates=['Snapshot'])
    except:
        snapshotDate = None

    if tableName in ["DCE"] and snapshotDate.Snapshot[0].date() == datetime.datetime.now().date() and snapshotDate.Snapshot[0] < datetime.datetime.now() :
        try:
            print('attempting to remove the latest snapshot from %s and update...' %tableName)
            with engine.connect() as conn:
                conn.execute('''DELETE FROM ibdrs."%s" WHERE "Snapshot" = (SELECT MAX("Snapshot") FROM ( SELECT * FROM "%s") AS Get_Snapshot )''' % (tableName, tableName) )
                print('Snapshot removed.... preparing for update')
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            print(tableName + ' Deleting the snapshot for the same day failed')        

    if snapshotDate is None or snapshotDate.Snapshot[0].date() != datetime.datetime.now().date() :
        print('loading data for %s' %tableName)
        with open(path+file) as f :
         try:
             rawJson = json.load(f)
             rawJson['authorizations'][0]['id'] = guid
         except:
             print(f.name + ' Check the JSON within')
             continue


        createSession()
        createJob(session)
        loadData(data, engine)
        print(tableName + ' Load Completed')
    else:
        print('Data already loaded for today for ' + tableName)
```

I can create a session and I get 3 different tokens in the cookiejar.  an sso_token, sentry_token, and an sso_rfp.  The api used to have no MFA, however they have recently implemented an MFA.  This MFA requires a redirect, but it doesn't actually occur until this section of the code:

```
docURL = 'https://api.com/jobs/%s/attachments/%s' % (docID, fileID)
data = session.get(docURL, verify=False)
```

I can setup through the script and I can get the DocID, I can use the DocID to check the docstatus, I can get the fileID.  As soon as I go to actually get the data the redirect happens and it gives a few 302s with 401s following until the 5th retry finally gives a final 401.  I am trying to figure out how to give the the sentry_token to the redirect, because that is apparently what it needs.  Instead it is trying to use the sso_token.  How can I use the right token for the correct domain with the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try two ways:

Using session.cookies.copy() will return you a RequestsCookieJar() object that stores session cookies. You could then use the .pop() method to remove the sso token from that cookie jar. After that, you can just provide the `cookies` keyword arg using the new cookie jar without the sso token.

```
      sso_less_cookies = session.cookies.copy()
      sso_less_cookies.pop('sso_token')

      session.get(session.get(docURL, verify=False, cookies=sso_less_cookies)
```

However, if you just need the sentry-token, you could try creating an empty cookie jar, and adding the sentry token from the original.

```
  cookies_dict = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)

  new_cookies = request.session.RequestsCookieJar()

  new_cookies.set('sentry_token', cookies_dict['sentry_token'],domain='example.org',path='/cookies')

  session.get(docURL, verify=False, cookies=new_cookies)
```